# Objects stuck in the wrong animation?

Tags: animation, game-engine

I was renaming animations and organizing my things, and I had nothing selecting while doing so. When I've finished, I've noticed that all my objects had changed their scale and form. How can I fix this? Thanks!

**EDIT:** It seems that the problem is in the rig, not the object. If I put the correct animation back, it won't fix itself.

Comment: maybe with click on the object alt+s and alt+r

Comment: @gladys thank for the help, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you only renamed them? Also do some of the objects in the animations take part in parent-child relationships? Cause breaking that and not keeping the transformation-offset comes to my mind.

Comment: @Lev there are parent-child relationships, and I have only renamed the animations, but it seems that I had a rig selected while doing so, causing all the objects to scale.

Comment: I see. Without being that familiar with the process, from the rigged models that I have downloaded I see some miniatures objects "guiding" the ones that are gonna be used. My guess is you changed the name of the miniatures and the other object has not updated the changed name. So go and update them. If I don't make any sense then forget about this comment, it is an assumptions from the rigged models I have worked with.